# Blank page when using VueJS and Django

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, frontend

I recently added VueJS to my Django project, following [this guide](https://medium.com/@rodrigosmaniotto/integrating-django-and-vuejs-with-vue-cli-3-and-webpack-loader-145c3b98501a).

I'm trying to run this template, to check if everything is alright:

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>Django Vue Integration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but frontend doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
<div id="app">
     <app></app>
 </div>
{% render_bundle 'app' %}
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->

</body>
</html>
```

It should just render the default VueJS page. The problem is that when I run Django using `manage.py runserver`, I will only see a blank page on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. I'm not receiveing any error in my cmd console, but in my dev tools I found this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Did you include the vue.config.js file exactly like in the article?
I had no issue getting it to work using his code, but am getting the same issue when I try to port it into my own project that I intend to deploy in product.

The one issue I did see was that the lodash template syntax is not getting interpolated for the favicon after mapping the backing to :8000

Comment: You need to run both servers & install `django-cors-headers` and whitelist your vuejs in settings.py (all explained at their website)

Answer (score 1):

Try running both servers at the **same time**, that is:

Django: `python manage.py runserver`

Vue: `npm run dev`